# I want add a row a specific postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I want add a row a specific postion. and i have all row id for example i have table In table rows have one button when i click on buttton row become instered below button click row

ASP.NET MVC COde

```
 <%For i = 0 To 9%>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="<%:i.ToString  %>" onclick ="alert('<%:i.ToString  %>')" /></td>
    <td>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
    <td>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
    </tr>
    <%next %>
```

Comment: Provide html and code you've done(if any) ?

Comment: You realise that your server-side code has little relevance to your client-side JavaScript..? Posting the rendered (X)HTML would help us to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = '<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>'
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(x).insertBefore(parentTr);
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9vXtV/1/

Comment: its not solve my problem my problem is i have 10 rows first cell of each row have button when i click on button rows become inserted at below for example i clicked 4th row buuton that means rows become instered below 4th row

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$("#your_table").append( $("#your_table tr:last").clone() );
```

This clones the last row and adds it to the table

Comment: its not solve my problem my problem is i have 10 rows first cell of each row have button when i click on button rows become inserted at below for example i clicked 4th row buuton that means rows become instered below 4th row

Answer (score 0):

Something more or less like this:

```
var newRow = $('#table tr:last').clone();
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').after(newRow.clone());
});
```

In this example I assume that the last row is an empty row on page load.